# How to delete an element from an array, which is in looping ?

Tags: loops, for-loop

Following is a psuedo-code example of what I am trying to do. I loop over an array and delete elements based on a condition. Now the problem is when I remove the elements the size of myArray is changing, and I get an out of index exception. Any ideas on how to get around this?

```
for i = 1:size(myArray)
    if myArray(i) == someValue
        remove_from(myArray, i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution for this problem is loop from the last to the first element.

```
for i = size(myArray):1
    if myArray(i) == someValue
        remove_from(myArray, i)
```